# populate Dictionary<string, List<string>> into arrayList on android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve a Dictionary> data from a server into an arraylist to populate it in a listview in android. I have done the connection to the server and what the response is in format:{"Key":["value1","value2"],"key":["value1",value2"]}.
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: Thnx for your response. I don't ask for code. I ask for the implementation mechanism or the big picture to understand. Should i use json mechanism or something else. Can you help please? thnx again.

Comment: I'd most certainly use JSON from the server-side and Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library within the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [AbstractMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)

And store that in an arrayist as follows...

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Object>>();
```

So now you have an arraylist of key value mappings which you can populate and use in your list view